# Usage of "same" as an adverb or adjective

Tags: adverbs

Could I take this usage of "same" as an adverbial phrase?

> To save on expenses, we moved into a shared office unit with another company **the same size as ourselves**.

Originally this sentence is from here. https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/move+in+with+(someone+or+something)

Comment: No: "the" modifies the adjective "same" forming a phrase which in turn modifies "size". Note that adverbs don't (normally) modify nouns.

Comment: What makes you think it might be an ***adverbial*** usage? I don't really care much about this "naming of the parts" approach to language learning, but what I see here is an optional ***adjectival phrase*** providing optional additional information about the immediately preceding ***noun*** ("company").

Comment: Hi @FumbleFingers Could I consider something like "which is" is hidden between <another company> and <the same size as ourselves>. For example) `~~~ we moved into a shared office unit with another company (which is) the same size as ourselves.`

Comment: You can usually introduce an optional prepositional element in between the noun and the "post-positioned" adjective, yes. That just extends the ***adjectival phrase*** without affecting the meaning. In this *specific* case, ***which is*** and ***that is*** are fine, but you could also use several other prepositions - ***of*** and ***with*** come to mind immediately as possible alternatives. But they're all just optional "verbal flourishes" (basically, stylistic choices).

Answer (score 1):

The phrase 'the same size as ourselves [sic]' is adjectival, not adverbial.  It modifies 'company'.

The use of reflexive pronoun, instead of object pronoun, shown in your quoted example is a separate topic.

Comment: "Size" is a noun, so "the same size as ourselves" must be an NP, not an AdjP!

Comment: 'another company the same size as ourselves [sic]' is a NP, but 'the same size as ourselves [sic]' is an AdjP.

Comment: No: it's an NP modifying "company". Note the article "the" which occurs with nouns, but not (usually) with adjectives. Not everything that modifies a noun is an adjective

Comment: Incidentally, it's not unusual for NPs denoting size, age and similar properties, to occur as post-head modifiers, cf. "a man my age" / "shoes this size" /  "the results last year" etc.